# Goodness of fit inside a data.frame by each row

Tags: r, categories, chi-squared

I have long set of frequencies (more that 70 rows that are locations) related to sex ratio in diferents populations of crabs in the line coast of Chile. The hipotesis that this sex ratio change from 1:1 from north to south, so I have two columns of frecuencies wich I want to identify where start the change. So in order to do it, I have a goodness of fit test. My idea is to put some expected probabilities on the data frame, so I can subset the rows where are significant diferences and do some test in those populations.

```
##Creating some fake data
female<-c(54,34,76,98,65)
male<-c(50,39,85,86,75)
female_exp<-c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
male_exp<-c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)

#The table as Data Frame object
table<-data.frame(female, male, female_exp, male_exp)
```

I want to compute Chi.Square and p.value (df=1) adding these information to new columms considering that each line has the 4 elements to do a 2x2 contengency table.

I have tried to make it by each row, but I got confuse about how to assign each value to the contingency table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want the following (EDITED following Vincent comment):

```
##Creating some fake data
female <- c(54,34,76,98,65,20)
male<-c(50,39,85,86,75,80)
female_exp<-c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
male_exp<-c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5) 

#The table as Data Frame object
table<-data.frame(female, male, female_exp, male_exp)

get_chisq <- function(x, prbs) {
             chsq <- chisq.test(x=x, p=prbs)
             ans <- cbind(statistic=chsq$statistic[[1]],
                          df=chsq$parameter[[1]],
                          p.value=chsq$p.value)
             ans
}

sol<-data.frame(t(apply(table, 1, function(x) get_chisq(x[1:2], x[3:4]))))
names(sol)<-c("statistic","df","p.value")
sol$hypothesis<-ifelse(sol$p.value<0.5, TRUE, FALSE) # tells you when your hypothesis is true
```

Hope  this helps.

Comment: I am not sure the numbers are correct:
for the first row, you compute 
`chisq.test(matrix(c(54,50,50,50),nc=2))`,
which is different from 
`chisq.test(c(54,50),p=c(.5,.5))`.